PyCharm error Python[42770:3955655] +[IMKClient subclass]: chose IMKClient_Legacy
Does anyone know how to get rid of this error? I'm new here and in coding with Python so I am doing this training, and every time I run the code (for both turtle and now tkinter) it shows this error <Python[42770:3955655] +[IMKClient subclass]: chose IMKClient_Legacy> I work on Mac Sequoia. I have the newest version of Python downloaded, I reinstalled PyCharm and Python and nothing.
Is there anything I could do? PyCharm runs the code fine but I don't know whether it may have an impact on the things I will do in the future and it's just annoying.

Try running the program through the terminal. If it works then the problem is most likely coming from pycharm.

Unfortunately I can't do it because I have a 'Command not found: python' issue but that is another story.

Please share your code. Without that, there's no way to help.

i got same issue : [IMKInputSession subclass]: chose IMKInputSession_Modern on content manager assetto corsa .exe

It's a MacOS Sequoia bug, nothing you can do about it until apple fixes it.
Already on the apple forums too, see here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255761734?sortBy=rank

Thanks for the links. Seams like it. After the new update from yesterday (macos Sequoia 15.0.1) the issue is stil there.
